# I can't input date in from on my web test using Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel-dusk

I attempt write code for test input date on form. My from use input date form w3s.

```
public function testAddCustomer()
{
    $this->browse(function (browser $browser)   {
        $browser->clickLink('เพิ่มลูกค้า')
                ->pause(500)
                ->assertPathIs('/customer/create')
                ->assertSee('ลงทะเบียนลูกค้า')
                .
                .
                .
                ->select('product_id', '1500ml')
                ->type('product_date', '17082017')
                ->pause(500)
                //->press('บันทึก')
                ;
    });
}
```

I can't input date on test Laravel Dusk.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using "keys"?

```
->keys('#date', '20171018')
```

Changing #date to your input selector, as is suggested here: 
https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/104

Comment: Thank you!  This is the only solution that works DEPENDABLY for me.   Using keys('#date', 2017, 10, 18) only works sometimes.